# Can overriding refer to data types in Java?

Tags: java, overriding

I am fairly certain that overriding ONLY refers to methods. Is it possible for it to also refer to data types? I know that in an instance of Derived, x would = 1 and not 0. But is this considered overriding?

```
class Base {    
    int x = 0 ; 
}

class Derived extends Base {    
    int x = 1 ;     
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question; in what sense would a _type_ be overridden?

Comment: I thought overloading was multiple methods with the same name but different argument signatures.

Comment: I guess your questions is the question, confusingly enough. It WOULDN'T be overridden because overriding only refers to methods... right?

Comment: I understand the difference between the two. This was a confusing question that was posed to me, is this a case of overriding? I said no, my friend said yes.

Comment: Correct, the @Override annotation only applies to methods ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html))

Comment: @JasonSperske Yes, but it also refers to fields as in this case.

Comment: This is an example of [hiding](http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/java/javaOO/override.html), not "overloading".

Comment: @runDOSrun This is not overloading. The answer in the Q&A you linked to is wrong to call it that.

Comment: @Radiodef Oh well, learn something new every day. My bad then!

Comment: @runDOSrun Well it is Stack Overflow's fault, not yours, that there are answers with incorrect terminology floating around with lots of upvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have done there is called *hiding*, not *overriding*. This is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) in the Java tutorials:

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through `super`, which is covered in the next section. Generally speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult to read.

Comment: Okay, I thought it was just called hiding. Thanks!